# How can we implement change notification propagation for WPF and SL in the MVVM pattern?

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, data-binding, mvvm

Here's an example scenario targetting MVVM WPF/SL development:

- **View data binds to view model Property
  "Target"**
- **"Target" exposes a field of an object called "data" that exists in the local application model, called "Original"**
- **when "Original" changes, it should raise notification to the view model and then propogate that change notification to the View.**

Here are the solutions I've come up with, but I don't like any of them all that much.  I'm looking for other ideas,  by the time we come up with something rock solid I'm certain Microsoft will have released .NET 5 with WPF/SL extensions for better tools for MVVM development.

**For now the question is, "What have you done to solve this problem and how has it worked out for you?"**

**Option 1.**

**Proposal:**

Attach a handler to *data*'s PropertyChanged event that watches for string values of properties it cares about that might have changed, and raises the appropriate notification.

**Why I don't like it:**

Changes don't bubble naturally, objects must be explicitly watched, if data changes to a new source, events must be un-registered/registered.

**Why I kind of like it:**

I get explicit control over propogation of changes, and I don't have to use any types that belong at a higher level of the application such as dependancy properties.

**Option 2.**

**Proposal:**

Attach a handler to *data*'s PropertyChanged event that re-raises the event across all properties using the name property name.

**Why I don't like it:**

This is essentially the same as option 1, but less intelligent, and forces me to never change my property names, as they have to be the same as the property names on *data*

**Why I kind of like it:**

It's very easy to set up and I don't have to think about it... Then again if I try to think, and change names to things that make sense, I shoot myself in the foot, and then I have to think about it!

**Option 3.**

**Proposal:**

Inherit my view model from dependancy object, and notify binding sources of changes directly.

**Why I don't like it:**

I'm not even 100% sure dependancy properties/objects can DO this, it was just a thought to look into.  Also I don't personally feel that WPF/SL types like Dep Obj belong at the view model level.

**Why I kind of like it:**

IF it has the capability that I'm seeking then it's a good answer!  minus that pesky layering issue.

**Option 4.**

**Proposal:**

Use a consistant agent messaging system based off of Task Parallels DataFlow Library to propogate everything through linked pipelining.

**Why I don't like it:**

I've never tried this, and somehow I think it will be lacking, plus it requires me to think about my code completely differently all the way around.

**Why I kind of like it:**

It has the possiblity of allowing me to do some VERY fun manipulations with a push based data model and using ActionBlocks as validation AND setters to then privately change view model properties and explicitly control PropertyChanged notifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've basically been using Option 4. When the state of the application changes (and therefore, data in the model changes), I send out a notification using the [MVVM Foundation](http://mvvmfoundation.codeplex.com/) `Messenger`. ViewModels that need this data for databinding can then subscribe to this message, update local properties accordingly, and call `RaisePropertyChanged()`* to notify the binding system that a change has occurred.

Yes, this is a different way of thinking about things, but I think it's worth it. It keeps your ViewModels very loosely coupled--they don't depend on your application's model nor the Views they support.

The biggest downside I've noticed is that debugging code that makes heavy use of the `Messenger` is more difficult. Basically, when an exception gets thrown, you get taken to a method in the `Messenger` class instead of the actual offending code. I think this is because because `Messenger` makes use of weak references. You learn to work around this problem, but it's definitely not ideal.

In a recent app I was working on, I decided to centralize all changes to application data in one large but simple class called `AppDataManager`. This class has fields for all the data that needs to be change tracked. After some initialization at startup, data changes are always or almost always initiated by the user. Thanks to two-way data binding, a user actions results in change to a property in a ViewModel. This change is then forwarded to the `AppDataManager` using a message. The `AppDataManager` then changes it's own reference to this data and sends out a message to notify any interested ViewModels that this data has changed. I usually include the changed data in the message (so the receiver doesn't have to know where to find the data). I'm not sure this is the best architecture, and I don't know how it would scale for large apps, but it seems to have worked well for me so far.

Obviously, an alternative approach to centralization would be a network approach where ViewModels subscribe directly to each other's messages. This very well might work, but I haven't tried it. I found that I could implement an undo system a lot more easily if all changes to the data were routed through one class. My data was also hierarchically arranged, so changes at the top of the hierarchy would need to cascade down to the "leaves" (e.g., if you change the map, you have to change the roads, and if you change the roads, you have to change the waypoints making up the roads). I found it much easier to manage this cascading centrally than choose an arbitrary ViewModel to do it.

*`RaisePropertyChanged` is a member of `ObservableObject`, which is also part of the MVVM Foundation. All ViewModels in my project inherit from `ObservableObject`.

**Note:** I'm thinking of switching from MVVM Foundation to the [MVVM Light Toolkit](http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/getstarted/), which seems to be a further development of the MVVM Foundation.

Comment: Are you sending messages from your model to anyone that is interested?

Comment: @Dan So essentially models can message views. That breaks MVVM layering.

Comment: @chibacity, Basically, models can send out change notification messages. ViewModels (not Views) can subscribe to these messages. Models know nothing about ViewModels, and ViewModels know nothing about models. They just know they need certain data, and the message provides that data. If you don't think this makes sense, what would you recommend?

Comment: @DanM Are you saying that Views "cannot", or "do not" subscribe to Model messages. Is it a design thing or a convention thing? I tend to use straight events from my Model->ViewModel. Plain events are a good fit as only those that are intended to know about events can actually expose events and subscribe to events.

Comment: @chibacity, Views do not, by convention. One difference between messaging (at least as implemented in the MVVM Foundation `Messenger`) and events is that the messenger uses weak references. If a subscribing ViewModel is no longer needed, it will be garbage collected once all other references to it are dropped. I believe with events, the Model will still hold a reference to the ViewModel even after all other references disappear (unless you explicitly drop it). Another advantage of messaging is that ViewModels don't need to know anything about the Model.

Comment: @DanM I use a different framework (Prism), but it has an implementation of the Mediator pattern i.e. messenger, with the same benefits e.g. decoupling and weak references, etc. That's not what I'm getting at - I know the score re. messaging in MVVM. In my mind models should not broadcast system wide messages where only specific models subscribe to them - even if this is adhered to by convention.

Comment: @chibacity, I'm not sure I understand the difference. Couldn't you pass an instance of your model into every ViewModel in your application? Wouldn't that essentially give every ViewModel the freedom to subscribe to any event on the model? Also, if ViewModels *do* use standard events to subscribe to model events, how do you release the references when the ViewModel is no longer needed? Do you write custom `Dispose()` methods?

Comment: I use mvvm light, I really like it.